# Is it possible to map different domain names to one IP address in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this. If it's not, kindly refer me to the most appropriate place.

I need to have customized domain names for my clients but only one instance of the web app. Is this possible? How do you I go about this?

Comment: There's not enough detail in the question to answer it. By 'clients' you mean customers and not network programs, right? I'm also guessing it's some sort of web application. If so, are you using TLS/SSL? And what web server stack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may simply be yes. But it's not up to AWS, but rather the DNS for the domains you plan to use. All the application running on the AWS IP address has to do is not reject the domain names given to the web server stack in its configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many domain names as you like to point to a single IP address using [AWS route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) hosted zones. You can create multiple A record in route 53 or you can utilise alias records.

> Amazon Route 53 is a highly available and scalable cloud Domain Name
>   System (DNS) web service. It is designed to give developers and
>   businesses an extremely reliable and cost effective way to route end
>   users to Internet applications by translating names like
>   www.example.com into the numeric IP addresses like 192.0.2.1 that
>   computers use to connect to each other. Amazon Route 53 is fully
>   compliant with IPv6 as well.
>
> Amazon Route 53 effectively connects user requests to infrastructure
>   running in AWS – such as Amazon EC2 instances, Elastic Load Balancing
>   load balancers, or Amazon S3 buckets – and can also be used to route
>   users to infrastructure outside of AWS. You can use Amazon Route 53 to
>   configure DNS health checks to route traffic to healthy endpoints or
>   to independently monitor the health of your application and its
>   endpoints. Amazon Route 53 Traffic Flow makes it easy for you to
>   manage traffic globally through a variety of routing types, including
>   Latency Based Routing, Geo DNS, Geoproximity, and Weighted Round
>   Robin—all of which can be combined with DNS Failover in order to
>   enable a variety of low-latency, fault-tolerant architectures. Using
>   Amazon Route 53 Traffic Flow’s simple visual editor, you can easily
>   manage how your end-users are routed to your application’s
>   endpoints—whether in a single AWS region or distributed around the
>   globe. Amazon Route 53 also offers Domain Name Registration – you can
>   purchase and manage domain names such as example.com and Amazon Route
>   53 will automatically configure DNS settings for your domains.